# Simple Javascript Onblur If else function

Tags: javascript, function, onblur, if-statement

This is my first week teaching myself javascript and i have run into a problem.

I am trying to create a simple mortgage 'loan to value' calculator. My calculator works fine but I am trying to set up a minimum value validation for one of my two form fields.

Here is a link to the page

[Link](http://alexmason.org/ltv.php)

My code is below

```
function calculate (form) {
    var propVal = form.propertyValue.value; var loanAmt =
    form.mortgageAmount.value; var type = form.mortgageType.value;

    var ltv = loanAmt / propVal * 100 ;

    var roundedLtv = Math.floor(ltv);

    if ( type === "First Time Buyer" && roundedLtv <= 91 )  {   
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= ("Your loan to value is: <b>" + (roundedLtv) + "%</b> <br /> We can help place your mortgage");
    }
    else if ( type === "Moving Home" && roundedLtv <= 91 )  {   
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= ("Your loan to value is: <b>" + (roundedLtv) + "%</b> <br /> We can help place your mortgage");
    }
    else if ( type === "Remortgage" && roundedLtv <= 86 )  {    
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= ("Your loan to value is: <b>" + (roundedLtv) + "%</b> <br /> We can help place your mortgage");
    }
    else if ( type === "Buy To Let Purchase" && roundedLtv <= 81 )  {   
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= ("Your loan to value is: <b>" + (roundedLtv) + "%</b> <br /> We can help place your mortgage");
    }
    else if ( type === "Buy To Let Remortgage" && roundedLtv <= 76 )  {     
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= ("Your loan to value is: <b>" + (roundedLtv) + "%</b> <br /> We can help place your mortgage");   
    }
    else 
    {       
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= ("Your loan to value is: <b>" + (roundedLtv) + "%</b> <br /> Unfortunatly we cannot help you place a mortgage");    
    }
}
```

All works ok until this point, where i am trying to alert the user that the loan amount needs to be larger than 45000. Below in the HTML you will see im am trying to use the onBlur function

```
function loancheck (propVal,loanAmt,form) {      
    if (loanAmt >= 45000) {
        document.getElementById("val1").innerHTML= ("Thank You"); 
    }
    else   
    {       
         document.getElementById("val1").innerHTML= ("Higher");   
    }
}
```

This is the html to go with it

```
<form name="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET"> Mortgage Type 
    <select name="mortgageType"> 
        <option>First Time Buyer</option> 
        <option>Moving Home</option> 
        <option>Remortgage</option> 
        <option>Buy To Let Purchase</option> 
        <option>Buy To Let Remortgage</option> 
     </select> 

     <br /> 
     Value <input name="propertyValue" type="text" value=""/><br />

     Mortgage Amount <input name="mortgageAmount" type="text" value="" onBlur="loancheck(this.value)" />

     <p id="val1"></p>

     <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Click" onClick="calculate(this.form)">
</form> 

<br /><br /> 
<p id="result"> </p>
```

Im sure I'm doing something fundamentally wrong but if someone could point it out to me i would be most thankful.

Comment: What is the issue here? No messages displayed in `#val1`? Please clarify in question.

Comment: Yes, no message was displayed in val1.

Comment: Thanks to everyone below who has had the patience to answer my question! I owe you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `loancheck` is called, the variable `loanAmt` is undefined, because not enough parameters were passed to the function. Consider cleaning up the function definition in the following way:

```
function loancheck (loanAmt) { // remove unused parameters
    var userAlert = document.getElementById("val1") // don't repeat yourself
    if (loanAmt >= 45000) { 
        userAlert.innerHTML= "Thank You"; // remove extraneous parens
    } else { 
        userAlert.innerHTML= "Higher";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `loancheck` you do this:

```
loancheck(this.value)
```

However, `loancheck` takes three parameters:

```
function loancheck (propVal,loanAmt,form)
```

Since `loanAmt` is a private variable within the `calculate` function, you'll need to call calculate first and then return the `loanAmt`.  Or, make `loanAmt` a global variable and update it whenever the user changes the appropriate field.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what actually happens :) 
But I see that your loancheck function takes 3 variables. Your onblur handler passes one variable but your function is expecting the second variable "loanAmt" to be there.  Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling loancheck(this.value) in onBlur

But your function definition has loancheck (propVal,loanAmt,form).

You are passing one value which get copies to proVal.

loadnAmt, form are undefined.